# How can I turn off certain tags for redcarpet in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, redcarpet

I have the following function in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def markdown(text)
    options = {}

    renderer = CustomRender.new(hard_wrap: true, filter_html: true)
    Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, options).render(text).html_safe
end
```

I am using a custom renderer. I am confused as to why I can use bulleted lists, italicized text, codespans, etc. I do not have them enabled in my render options.

I thought maybe I could just turn them off:

```
options = {
    codespan: false,
}
```

However, codespans are still recognized by redcarpet, and styling is applied. How can I turn off *all* tags from markdown and only enable a select few?

Answer (score 1):

Define method for codespan in your CustomRenderer

```
class CustomRender < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def codespan(code)
    code
  end
end
```

```
def markdown(text)
  renderer = CustomRender.new(hard_wrap: true, filter_html: true)
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer).render(text).html_safe
end
```

Now you can see no `<code>` tag is added when calling markdown

````
markdown('```some code```') =>  "<p>some code</p>\n"
````

You can overwrite all the methods mentioned here https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#block-level-calls